# How to draw a curved view like this one in android xml

Tags: android

I am trying to make a view like this one in xml but issue is that if I add using image view image fits inside screen same like if I add this to a layout background. How can I achieve this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi9dQ.png)

I am trying to make a view like this one in xml but issue is that if I add using image view image fits inside screen same like if I add this to a layout background. How can I achieve this

Comment: why not add this using vector ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be can use a vector to create something like that, put the vector image drawable into `ImageView` in your XML layout like this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--  
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" -> use this to make your image clear white space
        android:src="@drawable/img_background" -> make your vector as background
    -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView ... />
    
    <TextView ... />

    // your another code here


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is the result and anatomy of the XML Layout

[image]